# R function to install missing packages

Tags: r, nse, non-standard-evaluation

For one of my scripts I want to write an R function that checks if a package is already installed: if so it should use library() to import it in the namespace, otherwise it should install it and import it.

I assumed that *pkgname* is a string and tried to write something like:

```
ensure_library <- function(pkgname) {
  if (!require(pkgname)) {
    install.packages(pkgname, dependencies = TRUE)
  }
  require(pkgname)
}
```

As simple as is this function does not work.
If I try to run it like `ensure_library("dplyr")` it installs the package dplyr but then it fails because it trys to import `pkgname` rather than `dplyr` in the namespace.

```
ensure_library("dplyr")
Loading required package: pkgname
Installing package into ‘/home/luca/R-dev’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dplyr_0.5.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 708476 bytes (691 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 691 KB

* installing *source* package ‘dplyr’ ...
** package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

.... a lot of compiling here....

installing to /home/luca/R-dev/dplyr/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (dplyr)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpfd2Lep/downloaded_packages’
Loading required package: pkgname
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘pkgname’
2: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘pkgname’
```

Also, if I now re-run it it will install `dplyr` once again.

I realize this is probably due to R non-standard-evaluation and I have tried several combination of eval/substitute/quote in order to make it work with `require` but I couldn't succeed.

Can somebody help me understanding what is going on and if there is some easy-fix?

If a function already implementing this exists I would like to know, but what I am really interested is understanding why my code does not work as intended.

Comment: Use `character.only=TRUE` in `require`.

Comment: Thanks 42 that actually works, but I can't properly understand why.

I understand that with this option requires evaluates correctly the name of the package I want to install to "dplyr".

But why in the R console I can do require(dplyr) and require("dplyr") without character.only = TRUE? and why using something like 
substitute(pkgname), eval(quote(pkgname)) etc didn't work?

Comment: Because that parameter prevents the `substitute()` operation on the symbol `pkgname`. It's actually the substitute operation that is tripping up your efforts.

Comment: I think I still don't get NSE then.. I thought that inside a function substitute would actually create an expression but substituting any variable that it could substitute.. in this case I would expect that as.character(substitute(package)) (in require) would actually cause it to evaluate to "dplyr". Why it is evaluated to "pkgname" (the name of the variable I use in ensure_library?

Comment: It does get converted to an expression, but that expression is `pkgname`, and the as.character` is what is finishing up the coercion. `substitute` does not evaluate, so there's no lookup.

Comment: You can create a reporting function to show that  your attempts with substitute and quote would both be creating unevaluated R 'calls':  `subres <- function(x) cat( class( substitute(x) ) )`  tests: `subres(quote(pkgname))` # call ... and `subres(expression(pkgname))` # also call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on suggestion to use `character.only=TRUE`: If you look at the code for `require`, you see that the first step is only performed when the default value of 'character.only' ( `= FALSE`) holds:

```
> require
function (package, lib.loc = NULL, quietly = FALSE, warn.conflicts = TRUE, 
    character.only = FALSE) 
{
    if (!character.only) 
        package <- as.character(substitute(package))
    loaded <- paste("package", package, sep = ":") %in% search()
    if (!loaded) {
        if (!quietly) 
            packageStartupMessage(gettextf("Loading required package: %s", 
                package), domain = NA)
        value <- tryCatch(library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, 
            character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, warn.conflicts = warn.conflicts, 

# snipped rest of code
```

So leaving the default value of character.only in place forces the function to convert the symbol `pkgname` to a character value.

```
  as.character(substitute(pkgname))
 [1] "pkgname"
```

And since 'character.only' is also part of the `library` logic, and require calls `library`, you could have used `library`.

Further comment: You posted a follow-up to Rhelp and got some useful answers from Duncan Murdoch and Peter Dalgaard which clarified (I hope) this question. In the process I wondered whether your resistance to this answer comes about because of an expectation set up by the name of this function that *substitution* should occur but nothing was happening that looked like "substitution". That expectation seems perfectly reasonable I see now belatedly in retrospect. I think the correct name of the function could have been: substitute_but_only_on_the_basis_of_the_local_environment_or_second_argument. The more common use of `substitute` is with two arguments:

```
   y_val=45; a_val=99
   substitute( x + y == z + a , list( y= y_val, a = a_val)
   x + 45 == z + 99
```

There was no 'effort' to examine the values of any symbol in the first argument *unless* it had a named item in the second argument (which is named `env`.)

Comment: what I don't get is why package <- as.character(substitute(package)) is evaluated to "pkgname" (the name of the variable I use in ensure_library) rather than to "dplyr"..

Comment: Because `substitute` does not _evaluate_ its argument, meaning it doesn't use the symbol to go into the symbol-table and find what `pkgname` might have as its value. It's like `$` in this respect.

Answer (score -2):

The suggestions given above are already good and could address your problem. Nonetheless, you are re-inventing the wheel a bit there.

If you want to distribute R code, with documentation that has requirements on external packages and possibly needs proper testing, I would suggest that you make a package out of it. When the package is being installed, it is automatically ensured that all dependencies are available. Plus you have documentation with it and a place for your testing scripts. It keeps everything nicely in one place and is versioned at the same time.

Comment: Holger I am sorry, but you are missing the point of my question. I know you shoul use Depends Imports, roxygen2 etc when organizing your code in a package but that is not what I have to do now. I have to share a simple script and it seems quite an overkill in that respect to make an R package when I can just place a simple function at the very beginning and using it.